# Django signals - Wait for signal in function

Tags: django, asynchronous, signals, messaging, django-signals

I am using django and I want to send a signal from one function and and create a 'wait-point' in the middle of another function for that signal.

In more detail,
I am using a 3rd party api. So,

```
def foo():
   id = thirdPartyFunction(action='/bar')
   id.save()
   # send signal!
   return render_to_response('pleaseWait.html')

def bar():
   # initialize this and that
   # ...
   # WAIT FOR SIGNAL
   return HttpResponseRedirect('success.html')
```

How do I create a listener in the middle of a function. 
Currently, my understanding is that the signal dispatcher calls another function. I have no idea how to do this.

Thanks for your time and help :)

Comment: Not possible with Django signals. However, you could use something like Celery to run a task in `foo` and then poll in `bar` to determine when it's done.

Comment: You add asynchronous tag to this problem? `Django Signals` are **synchronous** .

Comment: The call to my third party app is asynchronous.

Comment: It's more common to poll the server every x seconds with javascript, rather than have the view wait for completion.

Comment: Thats exactly what i ended up doing! :)

Answer (score 0):

If both functions will be called in the same process, then it is possible but Django doesn't make it easy for a reason. And that reason is there are better ways to do this such as with real async workers.

If you do need to do this, (I often use this to test signals), you can exploit how signals are run by Django (although this is subject to change in future versions. Django signals are all run in a big loop in the same process they are triggered, where the later subscribed receivers are called after the earlier subscribed receivers. So, you can do something like this in `bar()`:

```
def bar():   
    def callback(*args, **kwargs):
        status['triggered'] = True

    signal.connect(callback)

    # wait until signal triggered
    loops = 0
    while loops < 100 and not status['triggered']:
        pass
    if status['triggered']:
        # timeout logic to prevent hangs
    # do whatever you want after the signal triggered
```

If you want, you can even retrieve data from the signal in the callback and save it to the status dict, but don't tell anyone you heard it from me.